# Как правильно настроить плагин очистки кеша на вордпресс?

Tags: wordpress, кэширование

Изменения в коде страницы появляются через несколько часов после изменений. Загрузила плагин - WP Fastest Cache.

Вроде по инструкции правильно настроила. Но не сразу, а после того как им воспользовалась и он не сработал. Но после новых настроек он все равно не работает. Изменения на странице есть, а в коде нет (когда просматриваю код страницы). Мне нужна новая информация для публикации в ФБ. Но фейсбук считывает старую информацию.

Вопрос - Может плагин неправильно работать, если изначально им пользовались не настраивая, а потом уже сделали настройку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того что бы получить актуальный код нужно удалить сгенерированный ранее кэш. В WP Fastest Cache это можно сделать выбрав на верхней админ панели *Clear Chache > Delete Cache and Minified CSS/JS*.
Если после этого вы видите старый контент это значит что у вас загружается локальный кэш что бы загрузить страницу не из кэша нужно нажать следующую комбинацию клавиш *crtl + f5*.

Comment: Благодарю за отзыв. Не помогает. Дело в том что проблема связанна с изображениями записей, которые помещены в теги <meta property="og:image" для Фейсбука.  Может из-за этого так долго обновляться информация? Размер изображений рекомендованный ФБ.